# .htaccess with two parameters redirects to a 404 page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect `/index.php?id=1&time=10` to `/first-10`.

**.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1&time=10
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /first-10/? [L,R=301]
```

when I access `/index.php?id=1&time=10` redirects to `/first-10/`, but it's a 404 page. Please notice last slash also.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to internally rewrite it back to its old-original format.
You must use `THE_REQUEST` to avoid an infinite loop

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(?:index\.php)?\?id=1&time=10\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /first-10? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^first-10$ /index.php?id=1&time=10 [L]
```

- Both `http://example.com/index.php?id=1&time=10` and `http://example.com/?id=1&time=10` will redirect to `http://example.com/first-10`.
- `http://example.com/first-10` will internally rewrite it back to `/index.php?id=1&time=10`

Comment: I'm pretty sure he won't need to worry about an infinite loop because the first redirect is a 301.  Also, he'll need to modify the script to handle that URI, without a querystring.

Comment: Since OP needs a rewrite back, he will face a loop issue if he does not use `THE_REQUEST`. And yes, it is mandatory (otherwise, he get a 404 since it does not exist)

Comment: This works, but redirects to `/first-10?id=1&time=10`.

Comment: Make sure you kept `?` after `/first-10` in the first `RewriteRule`

Comment: Ah, I see why he'd need the RewriteCond directive.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using REQUEST_URI instead of THE_REQUEST?

Comment: No. If you use `REQUEST_URI` you'll get an infinite loop. That's why i've used `THE_REQUEST` to avoid matching incoming internal request from server

Comment: This may look weird at first, but if you give it a try with both `REQUEST_URI` and `THE_REQUEST` you'll understand quickly how it works

Answer (score 0):

If really the problem is .htaccess, the result page is correct and the redirection is called, I tinking in:

The "?" character betwhen first-10/ and [L,R= ???
Or the / after first-10 ???